# how to hide all tr with checked checkboxes?

Tags: jquery

heres my trial code which is it think wrong.

```
$('#findtable').find('[name="scripts[]"]:checked').attr('#removed').hide();
```

where #findtable is the id of the table, #removed is the id of the tr

Comment: Can you show a sample of your HTML code?

Comment: Seeing some of the html that you're dealing with might help.

Comment: may be you are using wrong brackets near scripts http://jsfiddle.net/2Wvqr/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#findtable').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').hide();
```

---

This obviously assumes that there is only one checkbox per row. You should be more specific about the `input:checkbox` selector. Probably a *classname* too.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for you (which I was making when you already answered): http://jsfiddle.net/2Wvqr/

Comment: @mVChr: haha.. I was just creating the fiddle. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Just like always with jQuery, there's more than one way to skin a cat. You can use the `:has()` selector. http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

```
$('#findtable tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').hide()
```

Comment: +1 for an elegant solution that does precisely what the question asks for ("hide all tr with checked checkboxes").

Answer (score 0):

I created sample with selecting checked checkboxes:
In brief you are able to use code like this:

```
$("form input:checkbox:checked")
```

Here is quick [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BkYcG/)